# jQuery fadeOut fadeIn problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Please look at http://jsfiddle.net/yXnWP/2/ and notice "View Recent Updates". Click that and notice how it transitions from Update to Register Form? Now continue doing that slowly and notice how the transition changes the 4th time about.  Here is the part of the code responsible for that. Please give me any advice, tips or suggestions that may solve this issue of the different transitions.

**MY QUESTION IS: Why does it transition one way the FIRST 3 clicks, then after it does a different transition? Refresh and it starts with the first transition for the FIRST 3 clicks and switches... Why?**

```
                            <div class='index-update-register-container'>
                <button class='index-updates-register-link' value='FadeOut' onclick="fade('reg', 'upd', this);">View Recent Updates</button>
            </div>
            <div class='index-updates-container' id='upd'>
                Updates
            </div>
            <div class='index-register-container' id='reg'>
                <form action='index.php' method='post'>
                    Register Form
                </form>
            </div>              


</body>
<script>
function fade(div_id_out, div_id_in, button) {
    if(button.value == 'FadeOut') {
        $('#'+div_id_out).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#'+div_id_in).fadeIn(500);
        });
        $(button).html("Register");
        button.value = 'FadeIn';
    }
    else {
        $('#'+div_id_out).fadeIn(500, function() {
        $('#'+div_id_in).fadeOut(500);
        });
        $(button).html("View Recent Updates");
        button.value = 'FadeOut';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is normal behavior of your code.what you are expecting?did you want to fadeIn and fadeOut run synchronously ?

Comment: No, I want the first div to fadeout, THEN the second div to fade in. It does this SOMETIMES and other times it appears to happen instantly without any fade.  I am working on a jsfiddle to show what I am talking about.

Comment: Maybe because in the else statement, you fade in the second div before you fade out the existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the jsfiddle I posted in the comment to muthu's answer.

You need to set one of the div's as hidden from the start, otherwise they are both visible and thus there is no transition.

A simple `$('#upd').hide();` at the top would solve this.

Updated JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/K7DbQ/

Comment: Thank You.  I knew I had to do that, I just wasn't sure how because I just began using jQuery and I am still very new at it.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the frame refresh interval has helped me before.

```
jQuery.fx.interval = 13 //This is the default
```

You can try increasing it to `30`. Increasing the interval means you are reducing the refresh rate and hence your animations will appear less jumpy since it reduces the load on memory resources.

More info on this [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/).